# Trick for AUTO_INCREMENT on composite keys in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, trigger, auto-increment

In contrast to the MySQL MyISAM-Engine, the InnoDB-Engine can not handle when one column of a composite primary key is declared as `AUTO_INCREMENT`. For example consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ExampleTable` (
     `KeyPartA` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `KeyPartB` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `Data` text NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`KeyPartA`,`KeyPartB`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now to simulate `AUTO_INCREMENT`, I learned, it is possible to create the following trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ExampleAutoIncrement BEFORE INSERT ON ExampleTable
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET NEW.KeyPartB = (
             SELECT IFNULL(MAX(KeyPartB), 0) + 1
             FROM ExampleTable
             WHERE KeyPartA  = NEW.KeyPartA
        );
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now inserts work correctly, generating auto-incremented values. Unfortunately I can not think of a sensible way to get the newly created key value.

Neither `LAST_INSERT_ID()` nor its C counterpart return it, as there is no actual `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. Also it is not possible to set the value with `LAST_INSERT_ID(IFNULL(MAX(KeyPartB), 0) + 1)` inside the `ExampleAutoIncrement` trigger, because MySQL resets the value after the trigger finishes.

The only way I thought of was to issue a `SELECT MAX(KeyPartB) FROM ExampleTable WHERE KeyPartA = ?` after an insert, which defeats the whole purpose of the trigger. I.e. I could just as well do this before the insert and increment manually.

Is there any way to get the incremented key value from the trigger or some other means of simulating the `AUTO_INCREMENT` I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is in [*migrating from myisam to innodb*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).  It goes something like:

```
  BEGIN;
  SELECT @id := IFNULL(MAX(id),0) + 1 FROM foo WHERE other = 123 FOR UPDATE;
  INSERT INTO foo
     (other, id, ...)
     VALUES
     (123, @id, ...);
  COMMIT;
```

Having a transaction is mandatory to prevent another thread from grabbing the same id.

Answer (score 1):

at least MySQL 5.6 - support auto increment column as part of composite index

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `int1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`uid`,`test`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

perfect work, so may be simples way - just upgrade MySQL

Comment: You are correct in that this is possible. But the result is not the same as with MyISAM. In your example `id` will be unique over the whole table. I want to keep the MyISAM-behaviour, which starts at `1` for every combination of `uid` and `test`. Otherwise I would have made `id` the atomic primary key and only put a usual unique index on the composite key.

Comment: Thanks, it other task. Just afraid (sure) - using trigger with select MAX() from same table will seriously slowdown work on big table and multi user environment.

Comment: I think he means add a hidden key, so you have 3 keys. id, keyA, keyB. Then you can use last_insert_id() as an index into the row that you need the KeyPartB of.